# It is possible to search for all email marketing / newsletter emails received by an account?

Tags: gmail

I've got a Gmail account I've been using for 10+ years.

It is almost full and I want to delete out some of the historic marketing / newsletter emails the account has received to save space.

Is it possible to search for all email marketing / newsletter emails so I can delete them?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Email marketing / newsletter emails, as an informal term, it's a very broad concept and could encompass practically any email not sent by your contacts. Gmail added Categories several years ago. I don't know if it was available since you created your Gmail account. It has a Promotion Category but it's uncertain if that is something that could be what you are looking for. Without more details, basically, you should learn about email headers and how Search, Filters, Labels, Categories and other features work. You might start by deleting emails not coming from your contacts.

Comment: Or maybe you should start by learning how the Categories work and focus on deleting email having the Promotions category.